# String separation by commas, but with a condition (ignore comma separated single word)

Tags: python, regex

With the following code (a bit messy, I acknowledge) I separate a string by commas, but the condition is that it doesn't separate when the string contains comma separated single words, for example:
It doesn't separate `"Yup, there's a reason why you want to hit the sack just minutes after climax"` but it separates `"The increase in heart rate, which you get from masturbating, is directly beneficial to the circulation, and can reduce the likelihood of a heart attack"` into  `['The increase in heart rate', 'which you get from masturbating', 'is directly beneficial to the circulation', 'and can reduce the likelihood of a heart attack']`

The problem is the purpose of the code fails when it encounters with such a string: `"When men ejaculate, it releases a slew of chemicals including oxytocin, vasopressin, and prolactin, all of which naturally help you hit the pillow."` I don't want a separation after oxytocin, but after prolactin. I need a regex to do that.

```
import os
import textwrap
import re
import io
from textblob import TextBlob


string = str(input_string)

listy= [x.strip() for x in string.split(',')]
listy = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in listy]
listy = [re.sub('(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)', '', x) for x in listy]
listy = filter(None, listy) # Remove any empty strings    

newstring= []

for segment in listy:

    wc = TextBlob(segment).word_counts

    if listy[len(listy)-1] != segment:

        if len(wc) > 3:  # len(segment.split(' ')) > 7:
            newstring.append(segment+"&&")
        else:
            newstring.append(segment+",")

    else:

        newstring.append(segment)

sep = [x.strip() for x in (' '.join(newstring)).split('&&')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below..

```
mystr="When men ejaculate, it releases a slew of chemicals including oxytocin, vasopressin, and prolactin, all of which naturally help you hit the pillow."

rExp=r",(?!\s+(?:and\s+)?\w+,)"
mylst=re.compile(rExp).split(mystr)
print(mylst)
```

should give the below output..

```
['When men ejaculate', ' it releases a slew of chemicals including oxytocin, vasopressin, and prolactin', ' all of which naturally help you hit the pillow.']
```

Let's look at how we split the string...

```
,(?!\s+\w+,)
```

Use every comma that is not followed by(`(?!` -> negative look ahead) `\s+\w+,` space and a word with comma.
The above would fail in case of `vasopressin, and` as `and` is not followed by `,`. So introduce a conditional `and\s+` within.

```
,(?!\s+(?:and\s+)?\w+,)
```

Although I might want to use the below

```
,(?!\s+(?:(?:and|or)\s+)?\w+,)
```

Test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/D8X2F9/1) 
Test code [here](https://repl.it/LLpB/0)

In essence consider replacing your line

```
listy= [x.strip() for x in string.split(',')]
```

with

```
listy= [x.strip() for x in re.split(r",(?!\s+(?:and\s+)?\w+,)",string)]
```

Comment: Although I believe proper english usage is `a,b and c` and not `a,b, and c`. Thus if incase of proper english then just `,(?!\s+\w+,)` would work.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @bulbus actually either is correct, the second is preferred (somewhat controversially) because it reduces ambiguity